# Allure report URL of specific case

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I am using google sheet api to auto collect fail cases imformaion from allure report json files.
What bothers me is that I don't know how to get the url of a specific case (I want to fill it into google sheet)

For example:
the specific test case url is [https://127.0.0.1/project/job/allure/”32-word](https://127.0.0.1/project/job/allure/%E2%80%9D32-word) long random number”/”16-word long random number”/

The question is

1. How to figure out the 32 & 16 -word random number?
2. Or can I customize the URL for each fail case?